# Drupal on Localhost (MAMP)

Tags: php, drupal, ftp, mamp, digital-ocean

I am working on a website for a client and I need to download a Drupal site and run it on localhost (MAMP).

The website is hosted here and I have FTP access
https://cloud.digitalocean.com/

I downloaded all the files from the FTP and pasted it in my "htdocs" but it's either a blank Drupal page or I get database access errors. I'm guessing I need to download a SQL database from the website, but how can I do this?

Comment: You might want to look into Drupal Backup and Migrate https://www.drupal.org/project/backup_migrate. You can use drush to take and restore the backup from the command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To summarize this, you can export database in many ways:

1. Backup & Migrate module, as ssnobody suggested.
2. If you have shell access you can export database with shell command:
   https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-import-and-export-databases-and-reset-a-root-password-in-mysql
3. phpMyAdmin (find one in Control panel or install one on your own), as Chandu suggested
   http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/setup.html
4. Use Drush.

I ordered it from easier to hardest....so try #1 first....

Answer (score 0):

you can open the cpanel of this website, open the phpmyadmin and export the database to an sql file, and import this file locally.

access the control panel here

https://www.digitalocean.com/features/control-panel/

Comment: Yes I would do that but I can't find the database/phpmyadmin on his hosting https://cloud.digitalocean.com/

Comment: I have, but there isn't a database section. There must be a database on here tho as its using drupal